# compare checkbox value on submit and display message using php

Tags: php

I want to display the message when user clicks on Others checkbox. There are other checkboxes too so I want to compare checkbox value and if Others checkbox is selected then I want to display the message. This is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Subject-1+Subject-2">Subject-1+Subject-2
  <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Subject-1+Subject-2+Subject-3">Subject-1+Subject-2+Subject-3
   <input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Others">Others
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  name="submit" class="wpcf7-submit"><br><br>
```

php part:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if(!empty($_POST['subject']) && $_POST['subject']=="Others") {
                echo " <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='Javascript'>
                window.alert('You wish to select other combo apart from given in above list. Kindly contact incharge of this institute.');
                </SCRIPT>";
            }
}
```

This code is not working. What changes should I make??

Comment: _"This code is not working"_ - How? What happens? Error message? Wrong result?

Comment: no error... No result... that alert is not displaying which should be displayed...

Comment: Also, when you're using `name="subject[]"`, then `$_POST['subject']` will be an _array_, not a string since it allows for multiple values. Try: `in_array('Others', $_POST['subject'])` instead to check if any of the values in the array contains that string.

Comment: okay so how can I compare the value of subject[] array and display that message?

Comment: are you trying to compare first and second check box

Comment: no I am checking whether the selected value is "Others" or no... if it is Others then it should display the message

Comment: When looking at your code, do you really mean to use checkboxes? I'm not sure in which context this is used, but it kind of looks like you should use a radio input instead (that only allows for one to be selected).

Comment: you can use foreach to check. seleted or not

Comment: I need checkboxes not radiobuttons....

Comment: Then just go for [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if the array contains the value `Others`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `subject[]` is an array in

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Others">
```

is an array type. So you should validate `subject` field as array as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['subject']) && in_array("Others", $_POST['subject'])) {
        echo " <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='Javascript'>
                window.alert('You wish to select other combo apart from given in above list. Kindly contact incharge of this institute.');
                </SCRIPT>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like given below. you are free to use `in_array()` but if you want to use the second condition with it use foreach like this.

```
if (in_array("Others", $_POST['subject'])) {
            echo 'selected ';
        }
        else{
            //do something
        }
```

OR

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $results=$_POST['subject'];
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result==='Others') {
            echo 'selected ';
        }
        else{
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Submit"){
    if(isset($_POST['subject'])){
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        if(in_array('Others', $subject)){
            echo "<script>alert('You wish to select other combo apart from given in above list. Kindly contact incharge of this institute.');</script>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('You wish to select other combo apart from given in above list. Kindly contact incharge of this institute.');</script>";
    }
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Subject-1+Subject-2">Subject-1+Subject-2
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Subject-1+Subject-2+Subject-3">Subject-1+Subject-2+Subject-3
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]" value="Others">Others
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  name="submit" class="wpcf7-submit"><br><br>
</form>
```